# Bring or get? Which sentence is better?

Tags: word-usage

I left my bag in my friend's room. How do I ask for it 
Can you bring it tommorow ? OR Can you get it tomorrow?

Comment: Who are you asking? What are you asking them to do? Who's coming to whom? Your question lacks specifics of the context.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you bring my bag tomorrow?

*Bring* implies that someone is already in a place where they can pick up the bag. It doesn't necessarily mean the person asking wants to possess the bag, though; it might mean that the bag is required for some activity. But it probably means the latter. The key notion is expressed by the first and main definition of *bring*: [to carry, convey, lead, or cause to go along to another place](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bring). This says nothing about "fetch" or "get" (which are different ideas).

> Can you get my bag tomorrow?

*Get* implies that the person is somewhere else and would have to make a trip to the bag's location in order to pick it up. *Get* also makes no guarantee that the person asking is even interested in having the bag. It might mean that the person asking wants the person being asked to have the bag, or simply to remove it from wherever it currently is (e.g., in case it might be stolen or removed by another party). See definition 2 of *get* at TFD Online [to go after and obtain](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/get).

Note that this isn't *always* true. Language can be imprecise, and people can use *bring* and *get* interchangeably in either case, and the communication would be understood. And to be fair, *get* has an additional definition of "to go after and bring" (e.g., "Get me a glass of water, please"). But careful speakers would be more likely to use the verbs in the way I have described them above.